# watir-webdriver + RWebSpec

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver, rwebspec

I'm new in ruby and programming stuff in general. I have one, maybe silly question
is possible to use all the methods from [rwebspec](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rwebspec/1.8.2/frames) with [watir-webdriver](http://rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/frames). And if it is possible, please show me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

RWebSpec is a wrapper for all the Watir/Selenium-WebDriver methods. So by using it you are essentially using these underlying tools. There's no reason you need to explicitly need to use Watir-WebDriver.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer, but if a want to start firefox instead of default browser wich is internet explorer? With watir-webdriver i just